# Verify if an element of a list is in a string

Tags: python, string, list

Verify if an element of a list is a a string

I have a list of key words:

```
check_list  = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']
```

And a group of strings:

```
test_string_1 = 'hellor world ccc'
test_string_2 = 'hellor world 2'
```

And I want to verify if any of the elements of the list is in the string

```
for key in check_list:
    if key in test_string_1:
        print 'True'
```

But instead of printing a value return True or False

So I can do this:

```
if some_conditions or if_key_value_in_test_string:
    do something
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand right what you want, you can do:

```
def test(check_list, test_string)
    for key in check_list:
        if key in test_string:
            return True
    return False
```

or in a single line you could do:

```
any([key in test_string for key in check_list])
```

or use a generator expression, which might be advantageous for long lists since it will short circuit (that is, stop at the first `True` without building the full list first):

```
any(key in test_string for key in check_list)
```

Comment: Yeap, that's what I want.  Is it necessary to define a function? or could that be made using list comprehension?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez: you could use something like `any([1 in i for i in [[2,3], [4,5], [1,7]]])`.

Answer (score 2):

use built-in functions

```
>>> check_list  = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']
>>> test_string_1 = 'hellor world ccc'
>>> test_string_2 = 'hellor world 2'
>>> any([(element in test_string_1) for element in check_list])
True
>>> any([(element in test_string_2) for element in check_list])
False
>>>
```